# Why can't I convert an A* to a B* in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. I receive the error: invalid conversion from A* to B* for the line above:

```
   B *p3=new A(p2->operator+(*p1));
```

Here is the complete code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  protected: int x;
  public: A(int i=-31) {x=i;}
  virtual A operator+(A a) {return x+a.x;}
};

class B:public A
{
  public:B(int i=12) {x=i;}
  B operator+(B b) {return x+b.x+1;}
  void afisare() {cout<<x;}
};

int main()
{
  A *p1=new B, *p2=new A;
  B *p3=new A(p2->operator+(*p1));
  p3->afisare();
  //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `A` is not a `B` so what did you expect? You can't assign an `A` to a pointer of type `B`.

Comment: ok, I understand what are you saying but how whoul you correct that?

Comment: By creating an `B` instead.

Comment: int main()
    {
    A *p1=new B, *p2=new B;
    B *p3=new B(p2->operator+(*p1));
    p3->afisare();
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
  Like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your inheritance backwards here. If you have a pointer of type `A*`, it can point either at an object of type `A` or at an object of type `B`, since an object of type `B` is also an object of type `A`. However, you cannot have a pointer of type `B*` point at an object of type `A`, since not all objects of type `A` are also of type `B`.

Independently, you can rewrite the line

```
B *p3 = new A(p2->operator+(*p1));
```

as

```
B* p3 = new A(p2 + *p1);
```

which might make things a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism only works one way. Base pointers can point to derived classes because everything the derived class has everything the base class does. A derived pointer however, cannot point to a base because the derived class has things the base class does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class A
    {
    }

    class B:public A
    {
    }
```

Upcasting:  `A *a=new B;`  (Used mainly when overriding  )

Downcasting: `B *b=(B*)a;` it only works if the pointer you are trying to cast (in our case `a`)points to a concrete derived object.